# Why do unicode characters appear encoded within lists?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

The output of the program

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
j = "Jürgen"
jlist = [j]
print j, type(j)
print jlist, type(jlist)
```

is

```
Jürgen <type 'str'>
['J\xc3\xbcrgen'] <type 'list'>
```

There is nothing wrong here. `\xc3\xbc` is just the [`utf-8` encoding of `ü`](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/). What I'm trying to understand is the difference. Why does the OS X terminal (which otherwise handles utf-8-encoded unicode just fine) and the debugger (PyCharm) display the encoding within the list, but display the actual (un-encoded) character without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `print()` uses `str()`(pretty printing) to display its strings, `str(j)` will appear with the strange character.  `str(jlist)`, however, will get the string version of the list.  The list's `__str__` method gets its strings by using `repr()` on each.  `repr()` is the raw format.  That means that a tab will be displayed as `\t`, not as a bunch of spaces; a new line will be displayed as `\n`, not as a new line, etc.  The reason for that is that if you wanted to be printing a list, it is probably for debugging or testing.  In those cases, you really want to know what is going on in the background.